# Is dependency injection expensive in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

Consider the following example:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[testActiveTab]'
})
export class ActiveTabDirective {

    @Input('testActiveTab') active: boolean = true;

    constructor(
        private parent: TabbedContainerComponent, // <--
        private child: TabComponent               // <--
    ) {
    }

    // ...

}
```

Usage in template:

```
<test-tabbed-container>
    <test-tab>
        <!-- ... -->
    </test-tab>

    <test-tab testActiveTab>
        <!-- ... -->
    </test-tab>
</test-tabbed-container>
```

As you probably guessed already, this directive is used to mark an active tab inside the tabbed container component.

The possible problem, however, is that every time an instance of the `ActiveTabDirective` is created, the injector will seed the `parent` and the `child` properties anew, meaning, that *if there are `n` tabs in the container, `2 * n` initializations will happen*.

**The question:**

Is dependency injection an expensive operation in Angular2+? Or is it merely passing a reference, thus being cheap?

Comment: "that if there are n tabs in the container, 2 * n initializations will happen", not always. DI is about lifetime management too, so depending in the configuration, only references will be passed around and no new instances will be created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'expensiveness' here addresses the way [hierarchical dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection) works in Angular, and performance impact is the outcome.

DI cannot instantiate and inject components that aren't linked to compiled elements.

Providers are singletons (in the scope of current injector). If a provider is not defined in current injector but was instantiated in parent injector, existing provider instance is injected.

Although `Injectable`, `Directive` and `Component` classes are all injectables, Angular clearly distinguishes directives/components (defined in `declarations`) from regular providers (defined in `providers`), and they behave differently. Directives/components are instantiated by compiler, so additional instance cannot be accidentally injected.

```
constructor(
    private parent: TabbedContainerComponent,
    private child: TabComponent
) {}
```

will inject existing component instances or throw if there are none. Where 'child' is in fact 'self' because children weren't compiled yet and should be retrieved with `ViewChild` or `ContentChild` if necessary.